# Sequence of division and multiplication in matrices and vectors

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have (in python) the following operation (using numpy for matrices and vectors):

```
result = (A.dot(input)/b)
```

with `A` a matrix and `b`, `input` a vector. `A` and `b` are fixed, `input` is changing. Thus I would like to reduce `A` and `b` to a single element, either vector or matrix, which then can be combined by either a multiplication or a dot product with the input vector. Unfortunately I can not write

```
result = (A/b).dot(input)
```

after it will result in a wrong value. How can I else concatenate `A` and `b` into a single element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend `b` to `2D` with [`None/np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) and then divide `A` divide by it :

```
Ab = A/b[:,None]
```

Then re-use `Ab` across those iterations with the matrix-multiplication, where you have `input` as the only variable :

```
Ab.dot(input)
```

As a sidenote, try to avoid variable names that are also Python builtin function names, in this case being `input`.

Sample run -

```
In [164]: A = np.random.rand(4,5)

In [165]: input1 = np.random.rand(5)

In [166]: b = np.random.rand(4)

In [167]: (A.dot(input1)/b)
Out[167]: array([ 2.80446671,  4.49821539,  3.73365285,  1.83176278])

In [168]: Ab = A/b[:,None]

In [169]: Ab.dot(input1)
Out[169]: array([ 2.80446671,  4.49821539,  3.73365285,  1.83176278])
```